# Updating dict with vars()

Tags: python, python-3.x

How does the following work?

```
import sys
env = {}
env.update(vars(sys))
```

From [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

> vars([object]) 
> Return the `__dict__` attribute for a module, class, instance, or any other object with a `__dict__` attribute.

What does the `vars` access then? Would it be what is defined in `import *` (so limited by `__all__`), or is it just every single global-level function, class, or variable in the file?

Comment: It is literally the `globals()` dict for that module object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the namespace of the module. So, consider we have the following toy module, `test.py`:

```
(base) juanarrivillaga@50-254-139-253-static ~ % cat test.py
def foo():
    return globals()

def bar():
    print(x)
```

Then,

```
>>> import test
>>> test_globals = test.foo()
>>> test_globals is vars(test)
True
>>> vars(test)['x'] = 'banana'
>>> test.bar()
banana
```

This is analogous to any object. `__dict__` contains the *namespace* of an object. The *namespace* of a module *is the global namespace of that module*. Also note:

```
>>> test.x = 'apple'
>>> test.bar()
apple
```

Comment: when you say 'module' does that also apply to a class/instance or non-global namespace?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 when I say *module* I mean *module*. But `vars` works on *any object with a `__dict__`*. A `__dict__` will act as the namespace of that object.